# Does every smooth curve of genus $\ge 2$ lie in a family containing an integral stable nodal curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over an algebraically closed field $k$. Does there exist a Dedekind domain $A$ and a stable curve $\mathcal{X}/A$ such that at two closed points $x,y\in\text{Spec }A$, we have $\mathcal{X}_x = X$, and $\mathcal{X}_y$ is an integral stable nodal curve (ie, a stable curve with one irreducible component).

Comment: I deleted a wrong comment.